# Changing values​ ​in attribute table and split it into different columns?

Tags: qgis, splitting, replace

How to change the values ​ ​in the table and divide it into different columns?
I have an example
[image]

I want to get a result

[image]

Comment: Is this example exemplary for all your use-cases, or would the differ significantly? What have you tried so far?

Comment: This is an old code of objects,i need to change them for new ones,removing the letters and _,then split the numbers into different columns.

Comment: How many different codes are there?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use regular expressions for this. As I understood, you want to extract the numbers before the `_` and after it and create two new fields out of it, where the second one should be null if there is no number after the `_`.

- For the numbers before `_` use: `regexp_substr("text",'(\\d*)?')`
- For the numbers after `_` use: `regexp_substr("text",'[_](\\d*)')`

Result:

|  | text | before_ | after_ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 16b_24f | 16 | 24 |
| 2 | 16b | 16 | *NULL* |
| 3 | 17b_23f | 17 | 23 |

Explanation: `(\\d*)` will match all numbers while `?` indicates that there might be or not some other character after it. `[_]` matches the `_` character, and `(\\d*)` extracts all numbers after it, but only if there is a `_` char, so we get `NULL` if there is none.

---

To turn e.g. `16b_24f_17c` or `16b_24f_17c_18d` into a list of comma separated numbers only, you could use something like

`array_to_string(string_to_array(regexp_replace("text",'([A-Za-z])',''),'_'),',')`

I am using arrays here and only one target column, so it is more universal and you can add as many `_12b_19x_09z_....` as you want. Otherwise you would need a new expression for every column, imagine having a string with houndreds of `12z_77a_...`, its just easier that way.

Explanation: First `regexp_replace()` removes all letters from `A-Z` and `a-z` from your string, then a new array with all left values will be built, separated by `_`. Finally we turn this array back into a comma separated string. Note that if you have more characters than `A-Z` or `a-z`, just add it inside the square brackets. You need to escape some special metacharacters like slashes. See [this great wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) for more details.

You could also use something like `array_get(string_to_array(regexp_replace("text",'([A-Za-z])',''),'_'),10)` to access a specific position of the array. Just replace the `10` with your desired position (starting with `0`). Using this, you could fill all your columns using quite the same expression instead of getting a comma separated list.

Comment: Sufficient answer, but could you add some explanations? Especially how `\\d+/*` work.

Comment: Which function should be in the case of 16b_24f_17c or 16b_24f_17c_18d?

Comment: Each digit in its own column or in one column with a separator ','

Comment: Thank you very much!!